# How to optimize a ALTER (Drop of column) for a table (type oracle) that's HUGE?

Tags: oracle, alter-table

**Preconditions**:

Table dimensions: HUGE 13 million records and still growing.

System: oracle.

**Problem**: 
Today we faced with a serious problem when we dropped a column from that table it took almost 20 minutes. A time that is critical for our delpoyment of some modifications. Without getting in more details is partitioning the table after column a solution for a faster DROP of column ?

**P.S.** The method presented in: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dropping-columns where we can drop first logical and then physical is not approachable in this case.

Comment: Why is `SET UNUSED` not approachable? This function is exactly the intended solution for your situation.

Comment: search the oracle doc for table redefinition, it may help you, though I second the comment by Wernfried.

Comment: Do you like to drop a column or do you like to redefine a table? For both I don't see the issue. Certainly dmbs_redefinition takes longer and occupies double space (and requires only a moment of service interruption)

Comment: one popular technique is to build a new table from scratch as desired, then use a insert as select to move the data over...once it's ready, drop the old table and rename the new one

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: Did you mean 13 *billion* records?  Because 13 *million* rows is a small number in Oracle.  I would expect the average 13 million row table to be altered in a few seconds.  What is the size of your table in gigabytes (as measured through DBA_SEGMENTS.BYTES)?  Is it possible the process only took 20 minutes because something else had the table locked?